# How to disable login use ssh key?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vps

I need login to my vps using user and password only and disable ssh key, how to do that ?
I am using GCP
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be done by setting:

```
PubkeyAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

However `PublickeyAuthentication` is much more secure than pasword authentication. I would disable the password authentication and allow only publickey authentication.

You can disable access to the server for a specific user with publickey authentication by removing the corresponding entry from the `authorized_keys` file under `/home/username/.ssh` and/or `/root/.ssh` depending on the user and settings in the `sshd_config`.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I will try tomorrow and give your feedback to you

Comment: Make a snapshot beforehand. Otherwise you might lock yourself out of the server.